# What is the image of the function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the image of the function $f : \Bbb Z$ x $\Bbb Z$ →$\Bbb R$, $f(a,b) = $ $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$

Attempt:

I think the image should be either all rational numbers OR all real numbers. But I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. If $a$ and $b$ are integers, we can write (with $k$ an integer)
$$a + b = 2k$$ in which case $\frac{a + b}{2} = k$ is an integer, or $$a + b = 2k + 1$$ in which case $\frac{a + b}{2} = k + \frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The image will be $$\{\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}\}\cup\mathbb{Z}$$.

Answer (score 1):

What will be the range of $(a,b) \mapsto a+b$?

Then what will be the range of 
$(a,b) \mapsto {1 \over 2} (a+b)$?